# Categorical sorting optimization

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, sorting, parallel-processing

Question: What is the best way to sort items(T) into buckets(ConcurrentBag)?

Ok, so I have not yet taken an Algorithms class, so I am unsure of the best approach to the problem I have come across.

Preconditions:

- Each bucket has a unique identifier (within each sBucket).
- Each sBucket has a unique identifier.
- Each item has a unique identifier.
- Each item has a property (bucketId) corresponding to the bucket it
  belongs to.
- Each item has a property (sBucketId) corresponding to the
  superBucket it belongs to.
- Bucket and sBucket id's are unique.
- I have a ConcurrentBag of items I wish to sort into these
  buckets.
- There are several hundred items.
- There are several dozen buckets.
- There are 3 super-buckets which contain the buckets.
- Each super-bucket contains the same buckets, though with different
  items within the buckets.

I am currently using brute force via a Parallel.foreach loop on the collection of items to compare the item's bucketId to each individual bucket using linq. This is incredibly slow and cumbersome though, so I'd like to find a better method.

I have thought about sorting the items based on their superBucket then Bucket, and then iterating through each superbucket->bucket to insert the items. Should this be the path I take?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Example of current code

```
ConcurrentBag<Item> items ...
List<SuperBuckets> ListOfSuperBuckets ...


Parallel.ForEach(items, item =>
{
   ListOfSuperBuckets
       .Where(sBucket => sBucket.id == item.sBucketId)
       .First()
       .buckets
       .Where(bucket => bucket.id == item.bucketId)
       .First()
       .items
       .Add(item);
});
```

Comment: `Each super-bucket contains the same buckets` - disjunct sets of buckets with pairwise equal bucketIds? (Try to introduce/explain terms/names at or before first use (superBucket→sBuchet in 1st precondition).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use parallelism for this, but there are a bunch of options.

```
var groupedBySBucket = ListOfSuperBuckets
    .GroupJoin(items, a => a.id, b => b.sBucketId, (a,b) => new
        {
            sBucket = a,
            buckets = a.buckets
                .GroupJoin(b, c => c.id, x => x.bucketId, (c, x) => new
                    {
                        bucket = c,
                        items = x
                    });
        });

foreach (var g in groupedBySBucket)
{
    // We benefit here from that the collection types are passed by reference.

    foreach (var b in g.buckets)
    {
        b.bucket.AddRange(b.items);
    }
}
```

Or if that's too much code for you, this is comparable.

```
var groupedByBucket = ListOfSuperBuckets
    .SelectMany(c => c.buckets, (a,b) => new { sBucketId = a.id, bucket = b })
    .GroupJoin(items, a => new { a.sBucketId, bucketId = a.bucket.id }, b => new { b.sBucketId, b.bucketId }, (a, b) => new
            {
                bucket = a.bucket,
                items = b
            }));

foreach (var g in groupedByBucket)
{
    // We benefit here from that the collection types are passed by reference.

    g.bucket.AddRange(b.items);
}
```

This is also assuming `ListOfSuperBuckets` is a given. If that was simply an artifact of your implementation, there'd be a simpler way even yet. This builds the list.

Beware, of course, because these are different--this one won't have any empty buckets for no data, but the first implementation could. We're also creating new buckets, which the first implementation doesn't; good if we need to, bad if you've already created them elsewhere. The first one could easily be modified to create them, of course.

```
var ListOfSuperBuckets = items
    .GroupBy(c => new { c.bucketId, c.sBucketId })
    .GroupBy(c => c.Key.sBucketId)
    .Select(c => new SuperBucket
        {
            id = c.Key,
            buckets = c.Select(b => new Bucket
                {
                    id = b.Key.bucketId,
                    items = b.ToList()
                }).ToList()
        })
    .ToList();
```

For what it's worth, all these `ToList` calls are meant to preserve the contract I assume you have. If you don't need them, you could benefit from LINQ's deferred execution by leaving them off. It's really a matter of how you're using the code, but that's worth consideration.

Comment: Nice! Quick correction on my part though, the SuperBuckets contain buckets that share the same id's, so for instance there could (and will always be) a bucket with id=1 in all three SuperBuckets. The bucketId corresponds to the type of item, the SuperBucket corresponds to a collection of buckets. Bad naming on my part. lol. Additionally, the buckets are created ahead of time by another process. The ListOfSuperBuckets is just an implementation of my own so I don't have to write each one out. There is probably a better way though.

Comment: The initial list of items is the only contractual segment. Anything else can be modified.

Comment: @AndrewDessin Ah, fair enough. See my edit. It's a little messier, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Dictionary` so you can look up buckets and SuperBuckets by ID instead of searching for them.

`SuperBucket` should have a `Dictionary<id_type,Bucket>` that you can use to look up buckets by ID, and should should keep the SuperBuckets in a `Dictionary<id_type,SuperBucket>`.  (`id_type` is the type of your IDs -- probably string or int, but I can't tell from your code)

If you don't want to modify the existing classes, then build a `Dictionary<id_type, Dictionary<id_type, Bucket>>` and use that.